# Why I can not use Alert or log function in celltemplate? How can I do?

Tags: authentication, alert, angular-ui-grid, celltemplate

I want to use alert or log function in celltemplate to see my object directly. But I can not. My code is like below:

```
columnDefs: [

              { field: 'Status', cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="alert("llk")">show</button>' },  { field: 'Log', cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="$log.log(Enums.Role)">log</button>' }]
```

My error is:
 Error: **[$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: alert(**
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.16/$parse/ueoe?p0=alert(
....

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code.

- There is a sintax error:

  - you closed your string here `"alert("`
  - if you want to do something like that, you can use `\'` inside `alert(...)`
- Second thing is that you cannot use function `window.alert` directly, see Context section on this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression. Basically, you should create your own function which will then call $window.alert.

Edit: pay attention to use `grid.appScope` prefix before calling your function.